# Flutter Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a flutter project, since yesterday there was an error like this

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :location
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
                  > Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/34.95.74.180] failed: Read timed out
```

I don't know, when I create a new project and it can run, but when I add the location library, there is an error like that.
Here is my pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.6+1
  http: ^0.12.0+4
  intl: ^0.16.1
  location: ^3.2.4
```

Also, this is my flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.985], locale en-ID)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[√] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using another internet connection. Previously I used a home WiFi connection, then I tried with a mobile hotspot.

Comment: using a VPN can fix this too